# Download file, stops at Responce.end()

Tags: c#, asp.net, download, response

I have a code that zips files in a folder and downloads the zip file
But after the download the code stops at `response.end()`.
I have code after that delete all the files in the folder, but it never goes there.

Someone knows why?

This is the code

```cs
protected void download_Click1(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{

 string dirRoot = "E:\\WashingMachine\\";
 string[] filesToZip = Directory.GetFiles(dirRoot, "*.csv", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
 string zipFileName = string.Format("cleaned-{0:yyyy-MM-dd}.zip", DateTime.Now);

    using (MemoryStream zipMS = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (ZipArchive zipArchive = new ZipArchive(zipMS, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
        {
            foreach (string fileToZip in filesToZip)
            {
                if (new FileInfo(fileToZip).Extension == ".zip") continue;
                if (fileToZip.Contains("node_modules")) continue;
                byte[] fileToZipBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileToZip);
                ZipArchiveEntry zipFileEntry = zipArchive.CreateEntry(fileToZip.Replace(dirRoot, "").Replace('\\', '/'));
                using (Stream zipEntryStream = zipFileEntry.Open())
                using (BinaryWriter zipFileBinary = new BinaryWriter(zipEntryStream))
                {
                    zipFileBinary.Write(fileToZipBytes);
                }

                //lstLog.Items.Add("zipped: " + fileToZip);
            }
        }

        using (FileStream finalZipFileStream = new FileStream("E:\\WashingMachine\\" + zipFileName, FileMode.Create))
        {
            zipMS.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            zipMS.CopyTo(finalZipFileStream);
        }
        string filePath = "E:\\WashingMachine\\" + zipFileName +" ";
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filePath);
        if (file.Exists)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
            Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            Response.Flush();
            Response.TransmitFile(file.FullName);
            Response.End();
        }

    }

    string[] directoryFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dirRoot, "*.*");
    foreach (string directoryFile in directoryFiles)
    {
        System.IO.File.Delete(directoryFile);
    }
    //lstLog.Items.Add("ZIP Archive Created.");
}
```

Comment: What do you think `response.end()` does? Did you google it? https://www.google.nl/search?q=what+does++response.end%28%29+do

Comment: Yes i googled it, if i dont have it the file dont gt downloaded
How can i proceed the code?

Answer (score 0):

I have changed to this and now it works

```cs
string filePath = "E:\\WashingMachine\\" + zipFileName + " ";
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filePath);
string Outgoingfile = zipFileName;
if (file.Exists)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Outgoingfile);
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.Close();
}
```

Comment: Please add more explanation than _"it works"_ to your post

Comment: Why does changing from TransmitFile and Response.End fixes the problem?

Comment: Im to new to this to know why it worked, i found the code on forum and tried it and it worked for me. thought i should show what i did for someone else with the same problem